# pass data between components with $scope.$emit()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, broadcast, emit

I'm trying to pass data between two components that have the same parent component (simple version: I have child1 component, child2 component, and both of them are children of parent component). Also all the components are as controllers.

Parent component is also a root component (it doesnt have any parent components) so I thought I had to use `$rootScope`?

If i want to pass a var `myVar` (integer) from child1 to child2 I guess I should do :

in child1 component:

```
$rootScope.$emit('myEvent', vm.myVar);
```

in parent component:

```
$scope.$on('changeTab', function(){
   console.log('parent', vm.myVar);
});
$scope.$broadcast('changeTab', vm.myVar);
```

in child2 component:

```
$rootScope.$on('changeTab', function () {
    console.log('child2', vm.myVar);
});
```

I am new to this and don't understand why this doesn't work, probably nothing big, if anyone could help me out would appreciate it :) ty !

By the way I get "undefined" in both console logs, but well `myVar` is defined properly in child1.

Comment: Why do you want to use events to share data between components?

Comment: could you try to replace `$rootScope` by `$scope`?

Comment: Thats what I have been asked, they told me I had to emit it to parent component and then broadcast it to my other child component

Comment: Same result Owl Max ... undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to broadcast to the child's parent:

```
$scope.$parent.$broadcast('hi', {
    msg: 'Hello there!'
});
```

`$scope.$broadcast` sends the message down the chain, but if you broadcast to the scope's parent then the parent will send the message down, which includes **both** siblings.

```js
angular.module('appModule', [])
  .controller('ParentController', [function() {
    this.hello = 'I am the parent';
  }])
  .controller('Child1Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    this.hello = 'I am Child 1';
    var that = this;
    $scope.$on('hi', function(event, data) {
      console.log(data.msg);
      that.hello = data.msg;
    });
  }])
  .controller('Child2Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    this.hello = 'I am Child 2';
    this.sayHello = function(str) {
      $scope.$parent.$broadcast('hi', {
        msg: str
      });
    }
  }]);

angular.bootstrap(window.document, ['appModule'], {
  strictDi: true
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px dotted #f00;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="ParentController as parentCtrl">
  <p>{{parentCtrl.hello}}</p>
  <div ng-controller="Child1Controller as child1Ctrl">
    <p>{{child1Ctrl.hello}}</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="Child2Controller as child2Ctrl">
    <p>{{child2Ctrl.hello}}</p>
    <button type="button>" ng-click="child2Ctrl.sayHello('Child 2 is cool')">Say Hello to Child 1</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your awnser, juste wondering, i guess putting simply $parent between scope and broadcast wont work, what should be written there then ?

Comment: `scope.$parent.$broadcast` should work, assuming scope is your controller or component's $scope object.

Comment: Hey, hope you had a great weekend! Just tried it, worked ty !